# longitudinal data with time-varying binary exposure in linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

Good morning, i am looking for some help with longitudinal data with time-varying binary exposure in linear mixed model. Outcome is continuous variable. I am going to use R and the lme4 package. I want to identify association between time varying smoking status and hemoglobin A1c with random intercept and random slope.

Here is a sample dataset and R code that i conducted. Is this right analysis for my hypothesis?

| id | smoking | HbA1c | visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 6.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 6.7 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 6.8 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 7.5 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 6.8 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.4 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.6 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.5 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 6.4 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 6.5 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 6.6 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 6.7 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 6.6 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 6.7 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 6.8 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 6.8 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 7 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 7.1 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 7 | 2 |
| 6 | 0 | 7.1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 7.2 | 4 |

```
data1 <- read.xlsx("lmm_test.xlsx")
model1 <- lmer(a1c ~ smk + smk * visit + (visit | id), data = data1)
a <- tidy(model, conf.int = TRUE)
a %>% select(term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
term                   estimate conf.low conf.high
smk                     -0.779   -1.22     -0.336
visit                    0.0373  -0.0218    0.0964
smk:visit                0.268    0.160     0.377
```

When the results of the analysis are as above mentioned, can i interpret that glycated hemoglobin increases by 0.268 in the presence of smoking status over time (1 visit unit) than in the absence of smoking?

Answer (score 1):

The model you have fitted has the following mathematical form: $$\texttt{HbA1c}_i(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{smoking}_i(t) + \beta_2 t + \beta_3 \{\texttt{smoking}_i(t) \times t\} + b_{i0} + b_{i1} t + \varepsilon_i(t),$$ where $b_i = (b_{i0}, b_{i1})$ are the random effects.

The presence of the interaction terms complicates the interpretation. If, at a particular time point $t$, the smoking status changes from zero to one, then the HbA1c at $t$ is expected to change by $\beta_1 + \beta_3 t$.